# local variable is undefined while it is defined above in IE 8

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8, console

[image]

In the image above, variable `sku` is undefined but just two step above it is defined as false. can anybody help me to come out this problem? I am totally screwed up with this IE 8 error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of the following: `var arr = [undefined];console.log(arr[0]);`? Can you see how this might relate to your issue?

Comment: are you sure that `p.json.skus[i]` is defined, I think it is `null`.

Comment: Because you posted code as an image, your question essentially is lost to any sort of search tool. Please replace your screenshot with actual code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an image of code rather than code.

Comment: This may well be a good question for StackOverflow, but it hasn't been asked well. Try posting code (as text!) which presents minimal case for your problem. Bonus points for using Stack Snippets, or at least a jsfiddle/codepen.

Answer (score 1):

`sku` Is `undefined` after the assignment `sku = p.json.skus[i]`, so I suppose it's `p.json.skus[i]` that is `undefined`.